# How is the ExcludeFromBuild itemgroup supposed to work in Web Deployment Projects?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, web-deployment-project

I added an ItemGroup for ExcludeFromBuild items **in the PreBuild target** in my Web Deployment project:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\Test\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After the build the assembly in the output still contains the compiled classes from the files in ~/Test. That's not what I expected.

Here is a snippet from [Using Web Deployment Projects with Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx) on MSDN:

> For example, by adding the following
>    section to a Web
>   Deployment project, you can exclude
>   the Test and Images folder from the
>   build process:
>
> ```
> <ItemGroup>
>  <ExcludeFromBuild Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\Test\**\*.*"/>
>  <ExcludeFromBuild  Include="$(SourceWebPhysicalPath)\Images\**\*.*"/>
> </ItemGroup>
> ```
>
> This is useful if you have test code
>   in the Web site project that should
>   not be included in the staging or
>   release builds.

Seems not work that way for me though. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I have found the problem. The ExcludeFromBuild item group is evaluated in the _CopyBeforeBuild target, which is called **before** the BeforeBuild target.

Doh!